# Complex truncation in a UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, truncate

Is there an easy way to truncate a `UILabel` like if you used Truncate Head and Truncate Tail simultaneously?

For example I would like to truncate this sentence: *"An example sentence to truncate"
like that: "… sentence to…"*

Note: My code is in Objective-C

Comment: What should be the criteria for the head truncation? first N words?

Comment: I do not care about the amount of words that will be truncated. But let's say that I want the same N number (of characters truncation) for the head truncation and for the tile truncation.

Comment: ok. Swift or Objective-c?

Comment: I edited my question. My code is in Objective-c